# Duda sobre BBDD

Tags: base-de-datos

A la hora de relacionar dos tablas se usa.

```
foreign key (atributo) references [tabla] (atributo);
```

Se relaciona la clave foránea de esa tabla con la clave primaria de la otra tabla pero siempre que veo ejemplos la clave foránea de la tabla que voy a relacionar coincide con la clave primaria de la tabla ejemplo:

```
foreign key (id_cap) references jugador (id_cap);
```

¿Puedo relacionar una tabla la cual su clave foránea no sea igual a la clave primaria de la otra tabla?

Comment: Si te refieres a que si puede hacer uniones de tablas con campos que no sean la llave primaria y la llave foranea; la respues es si, si se puede.

Comment: Claro. Pero no tendría mucho sentido, ya que al unir dos tablas lo que haces es completar la fila con información relacionada. Si esta "información relacionada" no es indicada con la clave que la identifica como única, entonces pueden haber ambiguedades (y otro tipos de problemas) ya que no se cumple correctamente la normalización. Me gustaría ver un ejemplo funcional y correcto de este tipo de uso (no solo un ejmplo de que se puede) , ya que la verdad, nunca he visto tal cosa :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te refieres al nombre de los atributos, sí se pueden llamar de diferente forma, por lo que en tu caso podría quedar así:

```
foreign key (id_cap) references jugador (id);
```

El único inconveniente de tener nombres diferentes es que si realizas un **natural join** no funciona por que el campo de la **clave primaria** debe llamarse igual que el campo de la **clave foránea**, en estos casos sólo basta con usar un **inner join** e indicar los nombres de los campos por los que se relacionan las tablas.

Si te refieres a los valores que tienen las **tuplas** el valor de una clave **foránea** debe existir siempre cómo clave **primaria**

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede.

Por lo general uno tiende a usar los mismos nombres de campo, porque identifican el mismo dato.

En algunos casos, hace tiempo, se usaba como prefijo al nombre del campo el nombre de la tabla, por lo que no era raro ver cosas como `foreign key (t1_id_cap) references jugador (t2_id_cap);` sin embargo dejo de usarse.

Los nombres de campo no impactan en las relaciones, y por eso se declaran explicitamente. Algunas bases de datos con diseñadores gráficos pueden sugerir las relaciones o tratar de inferirlas en base a los nombres de campo, pero esto igual no afecta ni la performance de la misma ni el uso.